# Round up to nearest integer key value in dictionary [Swift / iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a basic dictionary list similar to this:

```
let fanFlow:  [Int: String] = [100: "25 m/s", 350: "34 m/s", 420: "42 m/s"]
```

I'm trying to make it so that if I have a value in the middle of those figures, it will round up to the next highest number integer in the dictionary list.

For example: If I have a value "250", it will round that up to the next figure in the list, which will be "350", returning back "34 m/s".

Tried to google this and couldn't find anything that could help me.
Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired behavior when there is no key greater than the key you start with? You can use the keys property of swift Dictionaries to get an array of the keys, and then iterate over that to find the next largest key, and then get the value for that key. `let keys = [Int](fanFlow.keys)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
let fanFlow = [100: "25 m/s", 350: "34 m/s", 420: "42 m/s"]

func nextHighest(n: Int) -> String? {
  return fanFlow
    .keys
    .filter { $0 > n }
    .minElement()
    .map { fanFlow[$0]! }
}

nextHighest(250) // "34 m/s"
```

Or, in Swift 1.2:

```
let fanFlow = [100: "25 m/s", 350: "34 m/s", 420: "42 m/s"]

func nextHighest(n: Int) -> String? {

  let higher = fanFlow.keys.filter { $0 > n }.array

  return higher.isEmpty ? nil : fanFlow[minElement(higher)]!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let fanFlow:  [Int: String] = [100: "25 m/s", 350: "34 m/s", 420: "42 m/s"]
let fanFlowKeys = fanFlow.keys.array.sorted(<)

func getFanFlow(input:Int) -> String {
    for key in fanFlowKeys {
        if input <= key {
            return fanFlow[key]!
        }
    }
    return ""
}

getFanFlow(250)    // "34 m/s"
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed also! I gave the other answer the correct answer as they were first to reply.

Comment: @DisplayName no worries